# context deadline exceeded - IPFS

Tags: ipfs

I'm trying to publish website to ipfs using below command

```
1. ipfs add -r my-website
2. ipfs name publish <hash of the website>
```

while publishing getting error as `Error: context deadline exceeded`. What does that mean? How to resolve it?

Answer (score 2):

It means that it took too long (more than 1 minute) to publish the data.

The built-in timeout will be removed in the soon to be released patch release v0.5.1.

---

More information on why this is happening is at https://github.com/ipfs/go-ipfs/issues/7244. If you don't want to wait for the patch release, or rebuild from the latest master, then you may have to retry a few times (in my tests a few days ago publish times were on average ~30s).

Note: v0.5.0 was recently released (less than a week ago as of this post) and contained a number of large upgrades to IPNS publishing performance. While some of the performance improvements are immediately noticeable, the lions share will only occur once more of the network upgrades.

Update: go-ipfs v0.5.1 has been released